# Unity | When swipe left trigger button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a mobile android game in Unity, and I have a menu panel that slides in from the right, using animation, when a button is clicked. Now I want to trigger the button to be clicked when the player swipes left. Basically I want to "click the menu button" when I swipe left on the screen without actually touching the button. This way it would trigger the animation and all other function of the button. Is it possible to achieve that? This is my script for the swipe detection:

```
//Swipe
private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private bool isDraging = false;
private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;
private void Update()
{
    tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            isDraging = true;
            tap = true;
            startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
        }
        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }
    }
    //Calculate Distance
    swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    if (isDraging)
    {
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        }
    }
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125)
    {
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;
        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            //Left Or Right
            if (x < 0)
            {
                swipeLeft = true;
            }
            else
            {
                swipeRight = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (y < 0)
            {
                swipeDown = true;
            }
            else
            {
                swipeUp = true;
            }
        }
        Reset();
    }
}
private void Reset()
{
    startTouch = Vector2.zero;
    isDraging = false;
}
public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
```

How can I achieve my idea and how to implement it to my game?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDK_3qXHAFg maybe this helps

Comment: @Lotan That's exactly the code I have for swipe detection (you can see it in the sample), that's ok, but I don't know how to implement it to trigger my button to be clicked?

Comment: something like: if (SwipeLeft){ myButton.doSomething() } ?

Comment: button.OnClick.Invoke(). This function launches the OnClick event from your button, do it in your "SwipeLeft" and you shall be fine